# Prove that $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{f_{i}}{2^{i}} $ is integrable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $ I\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n} $ be a box.Let $ f_{i}:I\to[0,1] $ be integrable functions.

Prove that $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{f_{i}}{2^{i}} $ is integrable function.

My first intuition was to use Weierstrass M-test, but we never proved it for multivariable functions and I cant see why would it hold.

The second intuition was to show that the set of discontinuities of $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{f_{i}}{2^{i}} $ is of measure zero, but im not sure how to show it.

Any help would be appreaciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about Fubini's theorem on the product measure space $I \times \mathbb N$?  The infinite sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is the integral with respect to the counting measure on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Are you dealing with Lebesgue or Riemann integral?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Riemann integral

Comment: The Weierstrass $M$-text does hold for multivariable functions, so you can use that approach.

Comment: @DarthLubinus I see, that makes the solution easy. Although, we havent proved it in class and this is a question from one of the past exams, so if anyone can suggest another solution that would be great.

Comment: while I would love to see a proof which avoids the $M$-test, I feel like any proof will essentially be proving (in a long-winded way) that the uniform limit of a sequence of Riemann-integrable functions is again Riemann-integrable. By the way, if you look again at the proof of the Weierstrass $M$-test; it doesn't matter what the domain of your function is; all that matters is that the target space is $\Bbb{R}$ (or $\Bbb{C}$ or really any complete normed vector space). The domain can be any arbitrary set non-empty $A$ (doesn't even have to be a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}$).

Comment: By "BOX" you mean a BOUNDED rectangle?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I get what youre saying, problem is we havent proved that the uniform limit of a sequence of riemman integrable functions is riemann integrable for a metric space that is not $ \mathbb{R} $ or $ \mathbb{C} $ so Im uncomfortable with this solution

Comment: @TitoEliatron yes, an $ n $ dimensional compact cuboid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F_k:=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{f_i}{2^i}$ and let $F=\lim_k F_k=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{f_i}{2^i}$.

Since $f_i\ge 0$ for all $i$, the sequence $F_k$ is non-decrasing, so by Monotone Convergence Theorem
$$\int_I F=\lim_k \int_I F_k.$$

But $f_i\le 1$ for all $i$, so (denoting $\lambda_n$ the $n$.dimensional Lebesgue measure)
$$\int_I F_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{2^i}\int_If_i =\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{2^i} \lambda_n(I)=\lambda_n(I)\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{2^i}\overset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\lambda_n(I)<+\infty.$$
So, $F$ is integrable.